# Bootstrap grid - why are my columns collapsing?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a little confused by the Bootstrap grid system.  I have a row which contains two columns, each of width 3.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <!-- My row of columns -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    Column 1
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    Column 2
                </div>

            </div>
        </div> <!-- End my row of columns -->

    </div>
</div>
```

Currently, when I shrink the width of my page column 2 drops below column 1 very early. However, I'd rather the columns remain aligned next to each other while there is still a bunch of empty space on the right (i.e. the remaining 6 unused columns).

How do I make it happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add classes for smaller breakpoints. Once you fall below a certain width (992px) `col-md-3` doesn't apply.

I would suggest the following:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
    Column 1
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
     Column 2
</div>
```

In this example you're telling bootstrap to make the columns 100% width up to 767px, 50% width up to 991px, and 25% width for 992px and over.

Also you need to add another row inside `<div class="col-md-12">` or your grid will have extra gutters and won't align correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-6">
         Column 1
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
         Column 2
       </div>
       </div> <!-- end of row -->
     </div>
    </div> <!-- End my row of columns -->
</div>
```